# Missing badges in flair

Tags: support, badges, flair

I placed flair on my [blog](http://marenostrum.blogsome.com/). It updates my reputation (Edit: Now that, it doesn't update anything) but my badges is one less than the actual. I have 3 badges but it displays 2; it doesn't take the autobiographer one into account, I feel. Not a big deal but obviously it doesn't reflect the same with my badges on askubuntu.com. Is this behaviour OK or is it some kind of bug?

PS: I couldn't create "flair" tag, system warned me as: "users with less than 150 reputation can't create new tags. The tag 'flair' is new. Try using an existing tag instead." If some of you in charge of such things feel that "flair" tag is suitable here, please add it.

Comment: The badges are cached to reduced overhead on the server.

Comment: I couldn't get your point Marco Ceppi. Its too technical for me.

Comment: @marenostrum that means that the flair and badges are not calculated every time, but are calculated time-to-time and STORED on the server as they are until the next recalculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering myself: 16+ hours after my report, data on the flair is updated. Can such a delay be acceptable? Unfortunately I can not accept fluteflute's answer because he says "You just need to wait a short while". 16+ hour is not that short.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to wait a short while - you only received the third badge within the last hour.

Comment: Working now for me :) http://askubuntu.com/users/flair/3781.png?theme=dark&reload=yes

Comment: No, unfortunately it is not working. 7 ½ hours after from my third badge, 7 hours after from your first comment and 6 hours after from your second comment my badges are still 2 not 3 on flair. I see 2 as well when I click the link you gave above. (In the recent minutes my badges went up to 4 but I don't mention the 4th at all.)

Comment: Here is a screenshot I took a few minutes ago.(Time is Turkish locale; GMT+3): http://i55.tinypic.com/4q6h3l.png

Comment: 15+ hours after my report and situation is still the same or even worse because flair system give up updating reputations as well. Its time yo search for a more dedicated bug reporting place.